# sending message to collection in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

How to show in the sequence diagram that an object is sending message to store another object in its collection? When the object is put to the collection for example to hashMap, message is sent put(objectInstance) to that collection object. I vent through many sequence diagrams but I cant find anywhere this to be shown in sequence diagram.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

A message is a message. So where is the problem?

[image]

This sends an `append` message to a collection passing `internalObject`.

Comment: Maybe the question was to also show that it is Object's Collection, which from this SD is not obvious.

Comment: That what I thought it should look like. Only problem I see that despite I went through hundreds of UML diagrams, I cant see anyone showing message being sent to a collection.

Comment: Because it's trivial, and SDs are not supposed to show trivial things. They are meant to show complex interaction parts and visualize them. You don't "program" with SDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use CombinedFragment of loop type.